# NoMethodError in Submissions#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I'm getting the following error:

> NoMethodError in Submissions#show
>   undefined method `comment_path'

I can login, enter a title and URL, and post a comment.  When I hit the "Create Comment button"

this is where it errors out:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>
```

Other than the error, I'm trying to ADD a Comment not DELETE one?

**_comment.html.erb**

```
 <%= div_for(comment) do %>
     <div class="comments-wrapper clearfix">
       <div class="null-left">
          <p><small> <%= comment.user.email %> <strong><%= 
          time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></strong> ago </small></p>
          <p class="lead"><%= comment.body %></p>
       </div> 
     </div> 
    <% if comment.user == current_user %> 
        <%= link_to 'delete', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 
            'are you sure?'} %> 
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def create
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])
    @comment = @submission.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
  end
end
  end
      def destroy
        @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was 
        successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

def set_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end


def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:submission_id, :body, :user_id)
end
end
```

**submission_controller.rb**

```
    class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_submission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

      def index
    @submissions = Submission.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @submission = current_user.submissions.build
  end

  def edit
  end

 def create
    @submission = current_user.submissions.build(submission_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.save
        format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was 
          successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @submission 
          }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: 
           :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.update(submission_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was 
   successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submission }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: 
        :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def destroy
@submission.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to submissions_url, notice: 'Submission was 
  successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
   end
  end

def upvote
    @submission = Submisson.find{params[:id]}

    @submission.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @submission = Submisson.find{params[:id]}

    @submission.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

def set_submission
  @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
end


def submission_params
  params.require(:submission).permit(:title, :url)
end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
    resources :submissions do
      member do
        put "Like", to: "submission#upvote"
        put "Dislike", to: "submission#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments 
  end
  root to: "submissions#index"


end
```

Comment: submission_comments GET   /submissions/:submission_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /submissions/:submission_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create

Answer (score 0):

For delete, you need to pass submission id like

Your code

```
<%= link_to 'delete', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>
```

After modified

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.submission, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

On the comment form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

Create action on comment controller, remove this two lines

```
@comment = @submission.comments.new(comment_params)
@comment.user = current_user
```

After update delete link then test for comment create if not creating comment still then follow the below code.

Now your comment create action look like this

```
def create
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.comments.create(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
end
```

That code from my project which already working, if not working on your side then if have your public repository then post URL or post full error trace.

**Update Based on GitHub Link**

If you run the `rake routes` then you will see the comment delete routes format like

```
DELETE /submissions/:submission_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

You need to pass `submission_id` plus `id` for comment delete

Update `link_to` delete looks like this

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.submission, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And your `destroy` action looks like this on the `comments_controller`

```
def destroy
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])
    @comment = @submission.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to submission_path(@submission)
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind when testing Delete functionality; my issue is that I'm trying to "Create" a Comment.

Comment: What is the actual error? please provide the error. I have updated the answer please follow this. @Royal

Comment: @Royal, your problem is unclear. Please fix your question above so that anyone can answer your question properly. Remove some codes that are not related.

Comment: Well, I add your code snipped and got:  Comment was successfully created.
Rick and Morty http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty
0 points by rcrc001@gmail.com about 4 hours ago | 3 comments

Comment: I think it's working now.  I'll keep testing but thanks for your time...I'll let you know either way.

Comment: Getting close.  The adding of Comments is working.  Now, when trying to display (Show) the Comments, got the comment_path error once more.  (http://localhost:3000/submissions/4)

Comment: I have updated the answer, see the update section @Royal

Comment: @foo-dev I guess I'm not understanding.  I haven't tried to delete any Comments yet as I haven't gotten them to Display.  When I click on the Comments link, on the home page, I get the on comment_path.

Comment: @foo-dev  When I click on the Comments link, on the home page, I get Showing C:/Users/Royal and Carla/Desktop/schwiftologyNews1.0/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb where line #10 raised:   undefined method `comment_path' for #<#<Class:0x07c238e8>:0x0bd16128>
Did you mean?  font_path

Comment: @Royal, sorry! I'm don't understanding what you are saying, the comment partial will be submission show page

Comment: @foo-dev so I just tried to generate another Comment and it says that it was successfully created but once I return to the Home Page the Comment count = 0 and the comment doesn't appear.

Comment: @foo-dev from the Rails Console: irb(main):001:0> Comment.all
  Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Comment id: 1, submission_id: 4, body: "What is a Rick and Morty?  :)", user_id: 3, created_at: "2018-02-08 01:10:03", updated_at: "2018-02-08 01:10:03">, #<Comment id: 2, submission_id: 4, body: "What is a Rick and Morty?  :)", user_id: 3, created_at: "2018-02-08 01:12:10", updated_at: "2018-02-08 01:12:10">, #<Comment id: 3, submission_id: 4, body: "What is a Rick and Morty?  :)", user_id: 3, created_at: "2018-02

Comment: @foo-dev Yes, I'm just trying to Display the Comments right now so I'm not understanding how my code is branching into Delete logic?

Comment: I modified the comment path to:   <%= link_to 'delete', submission_comment_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>

Comment: From the Show file: <div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial => @submission.comments %>
</div>

Comment: @Royal, `<%= render partial: "comments/comments", obj:  @submission.comments %>` then go to `comments` and run loop like`<%obj.each do |comment|%> <%= comment.body%>  <%end %>`